# EditText в Dialog - как добиться нормального поведения клавиатуры?

Tags: android, клавиатура

Всем привет, думаю, что каждый сталкивался с проблемой - клавиатура в `EditText` в `Dialog` не открывается при появлении диалога и не закрывается при его закрытии. Давайте в этом вопросе постараемся найти способ заставить клавиатуру вести себя в этом кейсе адекватно.

1. Открытие по показу диалога
2. Закрытие по клику на `touchOutside`
3. Закрытие по нажатию "назад"
4. При сворачивании приложения клавиатура остается поверх всего и везде

1) `requestFocus` - не работает ни в xml, ни в коде, это проверено, есть всякие лайфхаки типа таких

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(
linearLayout.getApplicationWindowToken(),
InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Но все это выглядит страшно, нужны какие-то лишние вещи, и вообще это скорее просто открытие клавиатуры в "никуда". Вообще, я считаю, что все манипуляции c `InputMethodManager` - это большой-большой костыль. Ну просто непонятно, где тут привязка к `EditText` и, вообще к `Dialog`. Вообщем, **открытие клавиатуры при открытии диалога** под вопросом.

2) Закрытие окна при касании на затемненную область экрана (`touchOutside`) закрывает окно если не выставлен `cancelable(false)`. Так вот, если клавиатура в этот момент открыта то можно наблюдать как она остается поверх всего приложения.

3) По нажатию на кнопку "назад" клавиатура остается а диалог закрывается если был применен тот самый `InputMethodManager`.

4) Если открыть клавиатуру и выйти из приложения то клавиатура остается поверх всей системы, то есть меню, других приложений, пока ее не закрыть. Этот баг также замечаю в других приложений, к примеру ВКонтакте на экране авторизации...

В библиотеке Material Dialogs все эти баги не наблюдается, все работает как надо, но не понятно как (не найду этого "волшебного кода" в исходниках), также скажу, что вопрос касается скорее обычных `Dialog` (не `DialogFragment`)

Comment: Не сталкивался с подобной проблемой, можете расписать проблему более детально? желательно с кодом.

Comment: #4 наталкивает на мысли, что проблема где-то с клавиатурой.

Comment: я диалоги в который есть сложный контент (не просто текст) делаю через фрагменты или активити. чтобы клава открывалась при открытии фрагмента навесьте на editText.post() метод. в нём открывайте клаву. 2, 3  и 4 пункты хендлятся в лайфсайкл методах фрагмента/активити

Comment: @SviatVolkov, я так понимаю в метод  `post` передается `Runnable` колбек который вызовется когда `View` готова (знает свои размеры и т.п) Этот вариант я пробовал он не работал, может это применимо только для `DialogFragment`?

Comment: возможно, не могу ответить на этот вопрос)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сначала решить проблему в первом пункте, все остальные проблемы являются следствием, кмк.

```
...
dialog.show();
if (dialog.getWindow() != null) {
    dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
    dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
}
```